# How can I run Bulk Upload on a Remote SQL Server Instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Normally, the code below would work just fine.

```
USE ReconTest
BULK INSERT ReconTest.dbo.agg_boc_consolidated
FROM '\\UNC_Path\BACKUP TABLES\consolidated.csv' 
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n') 
GO
```

However, since I am trying to load data into a remote instance of SQL Server, I am getting an error.  I think this should be possible, by setting up some kind of proxy login credentials, or something like that.  I did some research on this, and it seems like that's the only way this will work.  unfortunately, I did not find any useful info on how to setup the proxy.  If my thinking is correct, and if this is the way to go, can someone please list the steps to go through to get this up and running.  I am using SQL Server 2008.  Finally, I don't have access to MS Configuration Manager, since it has been disabled by my IT department.  Ugh.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The UNC path must be visible to the remote SQL Server instance
- The account that SQL Server runs as must be a domain account **with network privileges** and rights to the remote file.

> Finally, I don't have access to MS Configuration Manager, since it has been disabled by my IT department. Ugh. Thanks.

This is set in the services control panel, which you probably also don't have access to.

The only other option is to transfer the import file to a location that the remote server has access to, like a local drive, and then run the import.

Comment: If I right-click the DB, then click Tasks and Import Data, I an import these files 1 by 1.  I was hoping to write a script to loop through all CSV files and load all into their respective tables, but it seems like a lot of this functionality is turned off.  Somehow, though, I feel like I should be able to setup a new Proxy, and get the server to recognize the files on the UNC path.  I just can't seem to get this working, so I'm not sure if that's the way to go or not.

Comment: You can use SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) to do this.